# Run Securetrading java jar file automatically on startup of centos server

Tags: linux, centos, boot, java

This is an extension of my previous post. Basically I want to start the following service automatically when the server is booted:

```
cd /usr/local/stapi java –jar StApi.jar
```

this is from Securetrading (payment gateway provider). Basically in a previous post someone suggested running it by:

```
su - username -c "java -jar /usr/local/stapi/StApi.jar"
```

but this would not work because their is an ini configuration file in the same directory as the jar file and the above command issued the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: stapi.ini (No such file or directory)
```

Please can anyone help with this also I may need to kill the service (not disable it from startup but just stop it) so please can someone advise of the command to stop it as well.

Thanks

Comment: So then `chdir` in that directory first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate multiple commands with a `;`

```
su - username -c "cd /usr/local/stapi; java -jar /usr/local/stapi/StApi.jar"
```

or you can use `&&` which will only run the next command if the last completed successfully

```
su - username -c "cd /usr/local/stapi && java -jar /usr/local/stapi/StApi.jar"
```